# Files on .tmp/public not being served on Sails.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, sails.js, bower

I have a grunt file called `bower.js` which uses `grunt-bower` and gets my bower dependencies and copy it to the `.tmp/public` folder.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.config.set('bower', {
    dev: {
      dest: '.tmp/public/bower_components',
      ignorePackages: ['font-awesome'],
      options: {
        expand: true
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-bower');
};
```

And I have modified my `compileAssets.js` to run this task when the app is build.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.registerTask('compileAssets', [
    'clean:dev',
    'bower:dev',
    'jst:dev',
    'less:dev',
    'copy:dev',
    'coffee:dev'
  ]);
};
```

After running `sails lift`, I see in my project folder that my bower components were copied over to `.tmp/public`, but when I access `localhost:1337` and I inspect the page sources, I can't find my bower components there.

What should I do in order to get my bower components to be served too?